# Apps crashing on one user only

Tags: macos, crash, user-account, preferences

Random apps are crashing as soon as they open, such as Acrobat, Word, Distiller and a few other smaller apps. I tried opening the apps on a 2nd user account and they open fine. I have also tried deleting my preferences via ▸ Users ▸ imac ▸ Library ▸ Preferences, but that has not helped.

This is getting very irritating!

I'm running Yosemite on an iMac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Mountain Lion, OS X is also caching preferences, what I personally think is an bad idea. :) It's like "Oh we made the Library folder visible again since Lion, let's make another hurdle against over-intelligent users deleting files and configuring on their own so we do not need to support their problems and to protect us!"-idea. :)

Back to topic. :)

On your path to delete the dark side app preferences, did you try:

```
defaults delete -app <YOURAPPNAME>
```

in Terminal.app? For instance, for deleting even the cached preferences of Apple Mail, you would invoke

```
defaults delete -app Mail
```

That resets all the preferences for Apple Mail and puts default values in the prefs file.

If you did, then try to load the default prefs you created:

```
defaults read -app <YOURAPPNAME>
```

**BEFORE** that, you could do displaying the prefs file for debugging that everything is ok:

```
defaults read -app <YOURAPPNAME>
```

If you see some binary trash, you can be sure the problem is there...

Comment: With some polish this could be a valid answer. Consider that your answer will be seen not only here but on Google search, so using improper language is not advisable.

Comment: Hi Buscar, you are right, sorry for that. Fixed that. :) Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that an OS X plugin called cDock was the issue and was causing the crash, since removing it from the plugins folder in Application support the apps open fine now. Thanks.